# Date completely changing when removing forward slashes

Tags: excel, date, replace, vba

I have been using the same code to format a date for a very long and all of a sudden I am having errors.

```
Columns("E").Replace _
What:="/", Replacement:="", _
Searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Range("E:E").Select
For Each cell In Range(Range("E1:E1"), Range("E1:E1").End(xlDown))
cell.NumberFormat = "00000000"
Next cell
```

I am getting a return value of 06/7/3849. Anyone know what is going on? I have tried various things to work around this and the date keep getting thrown off.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the source data, actual output, and output you expected.